# UIButton Change Size Depending on the Title

Tags: ios

I am using iOS 6.0 and xCode 4.5 with Autolayouts. I remember I used to resize the UIButton based on its content using [myButton sizeToFit]. But now it is not working. The UIButton does have a width constraint.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to check the width constraint and then make is >= somevalue instead of = somevalue